# Progress Indicator of PhpExcel Writer when writing data to an excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

What would be the best course of action to take if I wanted to show a progress indicator/interface when a user clicks and waits for PHP and the PhpExcel plugin to read from the database and write to the excel file.

I currently have a large Excel download option on our website, It takes around thirty minutes due to the massive size of data.. around 30 sheets and over 40k rows in each sheet.

I want the user to be able to minimize the screen and keep checking back on the progress for instance, 5%, 10%, 15%.

Comment: If it takes that long, then it's far better to run it as a background task and email the final file to the user rather than try running it through a web browser..... I'm amazed that you don't get a timeout long before 30 minutes have passed

Comment: +1. If you still want to report the progress of the creation, you'll need your asynchronous script to update some kind of database with the number of lines created and the total number of lines you expect to write. You update this data every N written rows and can therefore display progress to your users.

Comment: @MarkBaker So let the user request it through the broswer, then email later? Also, I have forced the script to allow timeout more than 30 minutes.

Comment: @Adrien Sounds good thanks for the comment